# Is there a way to split a string using custom character in github actions?

Tags: github-actions

I have a CI/CD string variable in the format `username:password`.
Now I want to separate out username and password into separate build variables to use in my actions. But I don't see any split-related methods mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) of GitHub actions.

Is there any way to do it in GitHub actions?

Comment: Depending on your GHA runner type and its shell, you may use the respective shell's utilities to achieve this. Please include your workflow in your question.